# Dart Decorators Like Typescript

Tags: typescript, kotlin, dart, decorator

Im Typescript background developer can i create decorators in dart or in kotlin like typescript ?
Like this code:

```
  const enumerable = (value: boolean) => {
  return (target: any, memberName: string, propertyDescriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    propertyDescriptor.enumerable = value;
  }
}
```